# Why am I getting a file upload error on Wordpress Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, forms, file, contact-form-7

I created a form with a file upload on Contact form 7 (CF7). 
Uploading the file is a must. 
Some times, the form successfully uploads the file and some times the upload fails.

What can I do?

Comment: When it fails is there an error message on the page or in your console? More information is needed to be able to give you any helpful advice.

Answer (score 2):

- No file permission in 'upload' folder.
- File size is over max value (contact7 has own param for that, but php.ini is define this param also).
- Type file is not acceptable.

Have You any error information after submit form?

Comment: my shortcode is: [file* my-file limit:5mb filetypes:jpg|doc|pdf|xls|docx|xlsx].

Comment: You wrote "Some times, the form successfully uploads the file and some times the upload fails." what this mean exactly? Did you can describe when it works and when don't? Did you every time use the same file?

Comment: When I've tried to upload every thing is fine, but some users says they can't upload file and received an error message